# how do i get an icon to display if there are child items on a list

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if its possible for me to get some small kind of indicator on parent menu items when a child item exists within in? below is the code for one of my menu items. Any advice would be awesome.

```
 <asp:LoginView ID="AdministrationLV" runat="server">
                <RoleGroups>
                    <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters, General Managers, Administrators, Managers">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div id="MainMenu3">
                                <div class="list-group panel">
                                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="#demo3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu3">+  Administration  </a>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
                                        <a class="list-group-item1" href="#Appliances" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Appliances">+  Appliances</a>
                                        <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="Appliances">
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Appliances/Fridge.aspx" data-parent="#Appliances">Fridge</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Appliances/Freezers.aspx" data-parent="#Appliances">Freezer</a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div id="list-group panel">
                                            <a class="list-group-item1" href="../../../General/Authorities/Authorities.aspx" data-parent="#Mainmenu3">Authorities</a>
                                        </div>

                                        <a class="list-group-item1" href="#Backgrounds" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Backgrounds">+  Backgrounds</a>
                                        <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="Backgrounds">
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../General/Religions/Religions.aspx" data-parent="#Backgrounds">Relegion</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../General/Ethnicities/Ethnicities.aspx" data-parent="#Backgrounds">Ethnicities</a>
                                        </div>


                                        <a class="list-group-item1" href="#Placements" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Placements">+  Placements</a>
                                        <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="Placements">
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Placements/New_Referral.aspx" data-parent="#Placements">New placement</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Placements/End_Referral.aspx" data-parent="#Placements">End Placement</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Placements/New_Placement.aspx" data-parent="#Placements">New Referal</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Placements/End_Placement.aspx" data-parent="#Placements">End Referal</a>
                                        </div>

                                        <a class="list-group-item1" href="#Education" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Education">+  Education</a>
                                        <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="Education">
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../General/Education/Schools.aspx" data-parent="#Education">Schools</a>
                                        </div>

                                        <a class="list-group-item1" href="#PoliciesDoc" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#PoliciesDoc">+  Policies/Documents  </a>
                                        <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="PoliciesDoc">
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Document_Forms/Document_Types.aspx" data-parent="#PoliciesDoc">Add/Edit Documents</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Document_Forms/Upload_Home_Document.aspx" data-parent="#PoliciesDoc">Update House Documents</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Group/Group_Document_Forms/New_Group_Template.aspx" data-parent="#PoliciesDoc">Update Group Template</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Group/Group_Document_Forms/New_Group_Policy.aspx" data-parent="#PoliciesDoc">Update Group Policy</a>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:RoleGroup>
                </RoleGroups>
            </asp:LoginView>
```

This is done using bootstrap CSS with a few minor colour alternations.

Comment: Perfect case for parent selector. Never implemented unfortunately!

Answer (score 1):

An element without childnodes is matched by the `:empty` pseudoclass, so to detect an element with at least one child you may use

```
:not(:empty) {
   ...
}
```

and maybe add the information in a `:before/:after` pseudoelement as a `content` or as a `background` icon, e.g.

```
:not(:empty):after {
   content: " (not empty)";
   display: inline-block;
}
```